# Could the toilet be used as an extra passenger seat?

Tags: faa-regulations, commercial-aviation, airline-operations

In the US, if the toilet had a seat belt, would it be legal for an airline to board one more passenger than the number of normal passenger seats, requiring that whoever used the toilet last must remain there until the next person needs to use it?

Inspired by: "A new engine inlet reduces vibration and cabin noise, the lavatory receives a belted seat allowing a fifth passenger and the Garmin G3000 gets computed take-off distance and stability/angle of attack protection."  -- [HondaJet Elite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_HA-420_HondaJet)

Related [Embraer Phenom 100](https://blogs.mentor.com/jvandomelen/blog/2011/02/09/take-off-and-landing-on-t)

Comment: Does that seat have a window?

Comment: So any passenger using the toilet can't return to their seat and sit with their travelling companions? It sounds awful, but I'm sure that Ryanair would love it.

Comment: Who goes first?

Comment: This is not new. Many business aircraft have seat belts on the toilet seat.

Comment: Please don't give the budget airlines ideas...

Answer (score 4):

When I was with Weber Aircraft we provided many lavatories for Boeing aircraft.  There was never any requirement for a passenger in the lav during structural tests/qualification.  Based on this I know that it would be illegal for have someone in the lav during takeoff or landing as it would exceed the structural qual test requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Most bizjets have very little room aboard, so they have to choose between lavatory seating and emergency lavatories located under normal seats. Emergency lavatories are a subject of some [horror stories rivaling Stephen King himself](https://www.celebritynetworth.com/articles/entertainment-articles/the-most-embarrassing-private-jet-flight-of-all-time/).

So, a small bizjet lavatory is rarely the same thing as a restroom aboard a passenger jet. The usual idea is to try not to use it at all, except when the only alternative is worse.

The Hondajet is unusual in offering a luxury as lavish as a fully enclosed restroom in such small a size. Still, it's a luxury, competing with extra seating, with the expected result of getting jump seat certification for extra flexibility. You wouldn't use that seat for the owner or their guests, but rather for staff or cabin crew.

If a commercial toilet on an airliner gets equipped with a seat belt, that seat will also be used as a jump seat for the crew. Some part of the cabin is already spent on providing crew seats, so that would get redistributed to revenue seating, and crew moved to the "new" seats. Needless to say few are looking forward to it.

Comment: I laughed so hard at the horror story that I cried!  Hahaha!  The poor fellow...